# Getting current URL from NodeJS's REQUEST module

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm using `nodeJS` and the [`request` module](https://github.com/mikeal/request). I'm trying to scrape data from a web page, but my data comes from an API which only gives me link-tracking urls.

For instance, this link:

```
http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-7227532-11292048?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbanoutfitters.com%2Furban%2Fcatalog%2Fproductdetail.jsp%3Fid%3D27074590
```

Actually leads here:

```
http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?id=27074590&cm_mmc=CJ-_-Affiliates-_-Threadfinder-_-11292048
```

***I'm aware that most of the link is embedded in the original URL, but this isn't always the case, so please ignore it / don't post answers which suggest regex'ing my way out of this!***

Using Request, how can I grab the page's `URL` (that is, the second link that the first redirects to) and store it as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
request(url, function(err, res, body){
    // get final redirect url
    if(this.redirects.length){
        var destUrl = this.redirects[this.redirects.length-1].redirectUri;
        console.log(destUrl);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [line #77 of request.js](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/request.js#L770):

It provides a internal array in response object named `redirects`:

```
var request = require('request');
var url = "http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-7227532-11292048?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbanoutfitters.com%2Furban%2Fcatalog%2Fproductdetail.jsp%3Fid%3D27074590";

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("%j", response['request']['redirects'])
  }
})
```

Then you can find JSON representation of an array with redirect history including status code and redirect URL. (I found there're 3 redirects out of the URL you've provided)

Comment: I'm a little confused about your usage here (especially the `%j` part), can you update your code to answer the specific use-case above?

Comment: the `%j` part means it will print out the JSON representation of an object. Guess you just want the URL only, but the truth is there might be a history of redirection where you can find the history when running my code.